I am having a problem with Fullcalendar, eventMouseEnter method is not working
I am having a problem with Fullcalendar, eventMouseEnter method does not work.
I want that when the mouse hovers over the event, it changes color.
I am creating an event with Laravel, so I only put the javascript code.
I am using Full Calendar for the first time in my life.


$(document).ready(function() {
  var SITEURL = "{{ url('/') }}";

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    events: SITEURL + "/fullcalender",
    displayEventTime: false,
    editable: true,
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
      if (event.allDay === 'true') {
        event.allDay = true;
      } else {
        event.allDay = false;
      }
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      var title = prompt('Event Title:');
      if (title) {
        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD");
        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD");
        $.ajax({
          url: SITEURL + "/fullcalenderAjax",
          data: {
            title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end,
            type: 'add'
          },
          type: "POST",
          success: function(data) {
            displayMessage("Event Created Successfully");
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
              id: data.id,
              title: title,
              start: start,
              end: end,
              allDay: allDay
            }, true);

            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
          }
        });
      }
    },
    eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
      var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD");
      var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD");

      $.ajax({
        url: SITEURL + '/fullcalenderAjax',
        data: {
          title: event.title,
          start: start,
          end: end,
          id: event.id,
          type: 'update'
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response) {
          displayMessage("Event Updated Successfully");
        }
      });
    },
    eventClick: function(event) {
      var deleteMsg = confirm("Do you really want to delete?");
      if (deleteMsg) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: SITEURL + '/fullcalenderAjax',
          data: {
            id: event.id,
            type: 'delete'
          },
          success: function(response) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
            displayMessage("Event Deleted Successfully");
          }
        });
      }
    },
    eventMouseEnter: function(info) {
      info.el.style = "background-color: red;";
    }
  });

});

function displayMessage(message) {
  toastr.success(message, 'Event');
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="card mt-5">
    <h3 class="card-header p-3">Laravel 11 FullCalender Tutorial Example - ItSolutionStuff.com</h3>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Can someone help me and figure out where the problem is?

I've fixed your snippet for you. A full HTML page does not go in the 'JS' section

I am using Full Calendar for the first time...in that case, why did you pick such an old version? You're using version 3, but the current version is version 6 and it has a lot more features, is faster and has less bugs.


Can someone help me and figure out where the problem is?

You are using Fullcalendar v3, which is quite outdated - and had a significantly different API.
In v3, the event is named eventMouseover, see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-clicking-hovering, and it passes different parameters to the callback function as well.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventMouseover:

Within the callback function, this is set to the event’s <div> element.

So what you need here, with v3 of Fullcalendar, is simply this:
eventMouseover: function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

And the counterpart for eventMouseLeave back in v3 was eventMouseout.
(Notice that I modified the way the background color is manipulated a tiny bit here as well. Directly accessing the property you want to manipulate, is a bit "safer", than assigning a new value to the whole style object, which can have other side effects. And even better would be not to use inline styles in the first place - but add/remove a class on the element, and then let the desired formatting apply via a corresponding rule in your stylesheet.)
